# String comparison order in Java

Tags: java, string, coding-style

Are both the String comparison methods below considered to be equal

```
public class TestString {
    public static final String CONSTVAL="foo";

    public boolean testString1(String testVal) {
        return testVal.equalsIgnoreCase(CONSTVAL);
    }

    public boolean testString2(String testVal) {
        return CONSTVAL.equalsIgnoreCase(testVal);
    }
}
```

or should one type of comparison be favoured over another?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should call equals on the constant since it avoids the risk of NullPointerException when `testVal` is null.

```
public boolean testString2(String testVal) {
    return CONSTVAL.equalsIgnoreCase(testVal);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One advantage of the latter is that it won't throw an exception if `testVal` is null.

I would expect the results to be the same, other than that.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance I would agree with @Jon Skeet, but then I noticed that **CONSTVAL isn't final**.

If it was final then testString2() is the safest and best way to test for equality.

Comment: My mistake, I should have added final to the const val

Answer (score 0):

When a constant value compare itself to another value you're almost sure to not have null value.

In your case,

```
new TestString().testString1(null);
```

will throw an exception, whereas,

```
new TestString().testString2(null);
```

wont.

But this kind of notation could be considered as [a yoda condition.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307)